# How to create a virtual storage space in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, file, virtual, storage

I'm using a third party SDK, and one of the method goes as following:

```
void ReadData(string filePath);
```

As you might have guessed, it requires a filename for the method.
I **do not** wish having to drop a (sensitive) file into the HDD, then use its filename as the parameter.

I was wondering if there is some way to create an isolated storage space from the user, so I can drop any files I want in there without worrying about people finding it?

EDIT: Strictly for Windows OS only.

Comment: It depends a lot on your operating system.

Comment: Oops ^_^ forgot about that. Edited.

Comment: You should tag your question as specific to Windows.

Comment: Probably.  Windows allows you to make many file-like objects that arent actually files on the hard drive.  I dont know specifics though.

Comment: How about creating an encrypted archive to store the sensitive files?

Comment: @Tibi  Does that mean I still have to decrypt it to the HDD when I need the files?

Comment: @EquinoxG If it is small enough (for example <500mb) you can decrypt it in memory, otherwise... you don't have much of a choice.

Comment: @Tibi I'm not sure how does it work; if I decrypt it in memory, how would I be able to get a "filename"?

Comment: It's not that difficult... after decrypting the archive, you will have a header with the offsets where each file is found (and eventually the file names). What you have to do is to create a pointer to the right address, and you got the data.

Comment: @Tibi you lost me there ^_^ I think I'm misunderstanding this, so if I pass the pointer (holding the address of the data in the RAM) as the filename parameter to the method, it will work as a normal file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7559/discussion-between-tibi-and-equinoxg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't worry about it.

You seem to have some misconception about who owns the computer and the data.  The user does.

If you're worried about other users getting access to the file, use the user's private documents or appdata directory, the ACL will prevent unprivileged users from getting to it.

But if your business model relies on denying a user access to the data inside their own computer, you need to rethink that.  There isn't any API to save a flawed business model.

Comment: +1, please don't go down the road of creating virtual filesystems, it's full of crazy.

Answer (score 0):

since the API of you call asks for a *filename* instead of a *file*, we have to asume that you really need a file, not a file-like-object.

A more specific name to the method would be "ReadDataFromFile". Take a look, is there another method that accepts the data itself, instead of a filename?

You are trying to transfer trust from the file owner to/and only to the program that does the call, you are mentioning in your question. So, if that all fails, take a look at File ACLs to restrict the access to the sensitive data, e.g.: https://superuser.com/questions/246280/what-are-windows-acls or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
You still have to put the sensitive file on disk (an worry about deleting it later), but access would be restricted.

Comment: Does the ACLs restrict access to ONLY the calling process?

Comment: it's not that easy. take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx